# Graph: Depth First Search (N citizens with pairs of friends)

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded, graph, depth-first-search

I have solved problem 10608 on UVA Online Judge using Python 3.5.1. My solution works, but it takes too long to run when the online judge evaluates it.

#### [Problem](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1549)

There is a town with N citizens. It is known that some pairs of people are friends. According to the famous saying that “The friends of my friends are my friends, too” it follows that if A and B are friends
and B and C are friends then A and C are friends, too.
Your task is to count how many people there are in the largest group of friends.

#### Input

Input consists of several datasets. The first line of the input consists of a line with the number of test
cases to follow.

The first line of each dataset contains tho numbers N and M, where N is the number of town’s
citizens (1 ≤ N ≤ 30000) and M is the number of pairs of people (0 ≤ M ≤ 500000), which are known
to be friends. Each of the following M lines consists of two integers A and B (1 ≤ A ≤ N, 1 ≤ B ≤ N,
A ̸= B) which describe that A and B are friends. There could be repetitions among the given pairs.

#### Output

The output for each test case should contain (on a line by itself) one number denoting how many people
there are in the largest group of friends on a line by itself.

Sample Input

```
2
3 2
1 2
2 3
10 12
1 2
3 1
3 4
5 4
3 5
4 6
5 2
2 1
7 1
1 2
9 10
8 9
```

Sample Output

```
3
7
```

```
testCases = int(input())

for x in range(testCases):
    temp = input().split()
    N = int(temp[0])
    M = int(temp[1])

    nodes = []
    edges = []
    for _ in range(M):
        temp = input().split()
        A = int(temp[0])
        B = int(temp[1])
        edges.append([A, B])

    counter = 0
    for y in range(N):
        counter += 1
        nodes.append(counter)

    hashmap = {}
    for h in range(len(nodes)):
        neighbours = []
        for j in range(len(edges)):
            if edges[j].__contains__(nodes[h]):
                index_of_node = edges[j].index(nodes[h])
                if index_of_node == 0:
                    neighbours.append(edges[j][1])
                    hashmap[h + 1] = neighbours
                else:
                    neighbours.append(edges[j][0])
                    hashmap[h + 1] = neighbours
    current_group = 0
    highest_group = 0

    def reset_array():
        visited = []
        for _ in range(1, N + 2):
            visited.append(False)
        return visited

    visited = reset_array()

    def dfs(at):
        if visited[at]:
            return
        else:
            visited[at] = True
            global current_group
            current_group += 1
        if at in hashmap:
            neighbours = hashmap[at]
            for next in neighbours:
                dfs(next)
        else:
            return

    counter = 0
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        dfs(i + 1)
        if current_group > highest_group:
            highest_group = current_group
        visited = reset_array()
        current_group = 0

    print(highest_group)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Review of your code

---

- You should [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535868/9751583) prefer the `in` operator instead `__contains__`. See @HeapOverflow's comment for more details.
- According to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should not prefer CamelCase for variable names. Use snake_case instead.

---

```py
temp = input().split()
N = int(temp[0])
M = int(temp[1])
```

Can be replaced with

```py
M, N = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

And the same applies for a similar case.

---

```py
  counter = 0
  for y in range(N):
      counter += 1
      nodes.append(counter)
```

`nodes` is just equal to the values from `1` to `N`, which is just equal to `list(range(1, N+1))`
Therefore, you can remove `counter` completely.

---

```py
  if index_of_node == 0:
      neighbours.append(edges[j][1])
      hashmap[h+1] = neighbours
  else:
      neighbours.append(edges[j][0])
      hashmap[h+1] = neighbours
```

Since `hashmap[h+1] = neighbours` is executed regardless of the if statement, you can move it outside the scope.

---

```py
def reset_array():
    visited = []
    for _ in range(1, N+2):
        visited.append(False)
    return visited
```

`visited` is basically just equal to `[False] * (N+1)`.
The whole function can be replaced to `return [False] * (N+1)`

Also, this is a personal preference, but you don't have to use a function for this.

---

### Function `dfs`

- `next` is an inbuilt function's name, and therefore it should be avoided.
- `neighbours = hashmap[at]` Since this is used only once, the assignment is unnecessary
- `else: return` this is unnecessary, as the function does that anyway

Here's how `dfs` might look after applying the above changes:

```py
def dfs(at):
    global current_group

    if visited[at]:
        return

    visited[at] = True
    current_group += 1

    if at in hashmap:
        for next_ in hashmap[at]:
            dfs(next_)
```

---

### Faster Algorithm

The `dfs` will take `O(N)` time, and since it's executed `N` times, the time complexity will be `O(N^2)` which is clearly not feasible.

A [disjoint set union](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html) on the other hand, will take a [lot lesser time](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/disjoint_set_union.html#toc-tgt-4).

Here's my accepted code that uses DSU:

```py
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    dsu = [-1] * n

    for _ in range(m):
        u, v = map(int, input().split())
        u -= 1
        v -= 1

        while dsu[u] >= 0:
            u = dsu[u]

        while dsu[v] >= 0:
            v = dsu[v]

        if u == v:
            continue

        if u > v:
            u, v = v, u

        dsu[u] = dsu[u] + dsu[v]
        dsu[v] = u

    print(-min(dsu))
```

In case you have any queries about the above code, do ask me in the comments.

---

Also, I guess you're switching to python from java judging by the fact you named a variable `hashmap`. If that's the case, welcome to world of python!

Comment: The answer you linked to doesn't say that we should always use `in` instead of `__contains__`. And I occasionally do use the latter for higher speed, for example like `map(s.__contains__, a)` or `filter(s.__contains__, a)`. I think that's good usage.

Comment: @HeapOverflow My bad, I completely forgot that case, I'll edit my answer to fix that point. Thanks!